# Xamarin.Forms - Make ActivityIndicator Disappear when Video Loads

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

In `Xamarin.Forms`, I have an `ActivityIndicator` and a `label` that pops up when a video is loading.  How can I correctly go about disabling it when the video has been fully loaded?

Below is my xaml **(Updated 4/26)**:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PreAppStructure"
         xmlns:roxv="clr-namespace:Rox;assembly=Rox.Xamarin.Video.Portable"
         x:Class="PreAppStructure.Page3"
         Title="Welcome to page 3">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>

        <roxv:VideoView x:Name="VideoView" AutoPlay="True" LoopPlay="True" ShowController="True" Source="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" />

        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="True">

            <ActivityIndicator Color="White"
                x:Name="loader"
                IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" 
            VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"

               />
            <Label x:Name ="loadingtext" Text="Loading...Please wait!" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

Below is my C# class, and one of my several attempts:

```
...
public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    public Page3 ()
    {

        InitializeComponent ();

        this.BindingContext = this;

        this.IsBusy = true;


        NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "Back");

    }

    async void OnDoSomethingLong()
    {
        if (!this.IsBusy)
        {
            try
            {
                this.IsBusy = true;

                //await long operation here

            }
            finally
            {
                this.IsBusy = false;

                await Task.Run(() => {

                    return VideoView;

                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you not know how to disable the ActivityIndicator?  Or is it that you're not sure when the video has finished loading?  Or both?

Comment: I believe I disable the ActivityIndicator with the line "this.IsBusy = false;", I would say the latter is what I am a bit fuzzy with.  My instincts tell me that the video has finished loading at "return VideoView", so I figure that IsBusy line of code goes after that, but that's not correct.  I've tried before the line as well, no luck.

Comment: Don't the controls disappear at all, or *do* they disappear, but not the time you'd like them to?

Comment: You can use IsVisible property just like IsRunning for change the visibility. Just add code in XAML Activity indicator  <IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">. and it works

Comment: since you don't actually show the code that loads the video, it's difficult to say when it completes

Comment: @Jason - I posted the full xaml code in my original post, let me know what you think

Comment: @SrustiThakkar  - I tried your code, but no luck.  Both the label and activity indicator are still visible when the video loads.  I updated my full xaml in my original post for no confusion.

Comment: @PaulKertscher - The controls work well for me.  My issue is that the ActivityIndicator (the spinning loading wheel) and label stay visible even when the video is playing.  I would like to have the indicator and label disappear when the video loads and plays.

I believe I need to set IsRunning and IsVisiblity to be false somewhere in the code, but I don't know where or if I need to change my code.

Comment: I don't see any events on the video player that will let you know when the video has loaded or play has started.  Other than monitoring the state for Playing, I'm not sure there is a way to do this.

Comment: @Jason Interesting, do you believe there is some workaround that I could take?  Any form of indicator to show that the app is loading and has not crashed would be fantastic.  I also found a sample project from the creator of the NuGet if that is any help https://github.com/Rod-at-Rox/RoxXamarinVideo/tree/master/Sample/Portable

Comment: I would probably contact the author and ask

Comment: @TomF, Sorry, My mistake. Try to set visibility of <StackLayout> instead of <ActivityIndicator>.

Answer (score 1):

You should use IsVisible property for to hide or visible activity indicator

-IsRunning property is used for spin the activity indicator but it won't applicable to hide or visible the activity indicator

- IsVisible property used for to Hide or visible the activity indicator it won't bother whether it spinning or not, it just do visible and invisible.

in your case use you should use both IsVisible property and IsRunning property, whenever IsBusy is true activity indicator is visible and it will be spin, if it false it won't be visible and spin.

Remove stackLayout and add activity indicator to child of Grid .

```
 <ActivityIndicator Color="White" x:Name="loader" 
 IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
 IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
 VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```